# WPF Button styling

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, styles

I'm trying to use control template to customise button in WPF.
I have the following issues:
1. On MouseOver the color of the button doesn't change to Red
2. When pressed it gives a wobbling effect

below is the xaml:
                
                    
                    -->

```
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Border Name="border"
                           BorderThickness="1"
                           Padding="4,2"
                           BorderBrush="DarkGray"
                           CornerRadius="3"
                           Background="{StaticResource ButtonDarkColorBrush}">
                                <Grid >

                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="content" Style="{StaticResource ShadowStyle}"/>
                                </Grid>

                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <!--<Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF4788c8" />-->
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF4788c8" />
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                                </Trigger>


                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="content" Property="RenderTransform" >
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <TranslateTransform Y="0.1" />
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF282828" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF282828" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Opacity" Value="0.7" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>

                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

Please advise
Thanks

Comment: why didn't you paste a complete style xaml ? low quality questions are soon flagged !

Comment: First issue: give your MouseOver Background Setter a TargetName="border" too.

Comment: @LPL - Thanks that fixed the 1st issue, any suggestion for the 2nd one? to get a default press effect rather than a wobbly one?

Answer (score 2):

Hi Melspring Try this code it works for me.

```
<Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Name="border" 
                BorderThickness="2"
                Padding="4,2" 
                BorderBrush="{DynamicResource BlueGradient2}"
                CornerRadius="5" 
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid >
                            <ContentPresenter 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                            Name="content"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
```